# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'left' Python

Tags: python-3.x, binary-tree

Hi everyone I am new to coding. I am currently doing leetcode Q110 balanced Binary Tree,
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'left'. Please help me!!
https://leetcode.com/problems/balanced-binary-tree/

```
# Definition for a binary tree node.
# class TreeNode:
#     def __init__(self, val=0, left=None, right=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.left = left
#         self.right = right
class Solution:
    def isBalanced(self, root: TreeNode) -> bool:
        def helper(root):
            left_h = helper(root.left)
            right_h= helper(root.right)
        
            if root == None:
                return -1
            if abs(left_h-right_h) > 1 or left_h ==-2 or right_h== -2: return -2
            
            return max(left_h , right_h)+1
        return helper(root) !=-2
```

Comment: it means that your `root` variable is a `NoneType` variable. Please check if you have assigned  value to it,

Comment: Thank you for your help I finally fixed the bug.